# Keyboard and mouse not reacting during Ubuntu upgrade

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, ubuntu-16.04, upgrade

I pressed Ctrl+L to lock the screen of my PC while it was upgrading Ubuntu from 14.04 to 16.04. The problem is that the PC now does not react to any interrupt from the keyboard or mouse(and obviously now I have a blocked monitor). How can I fix that?

Comment: Be more specific. What says the log? What s the pc doing after rebooting?

Comment: I am afraid to reboot the pc, seems the CPU is working hard and upgrade is still in process even though I can't track it.